Remote-Explorer: grouping of some ssh hosts
Is it not possible in VisualStudioCode to group the hosts somehow to become a better overview?
thanks a lot for any help.
Extension is: Remote-Explorer together with Remote-SSH
I searched in the internet, etc.
Thank you for any help.

Did you find a way? This is one of my biggest issue, my host lists is so long and disorganised.
